# Get blank view before the printer selection

Tags: ios, printing, swiftui

When I call the following code, I end up with a blank view before I get the printer selection view. Once I dismiss (swipe) the blank view, everything seems to work fine after that.  The calling code is shown following. I have a NavigationView defined in another view that led to the view where this call is made. Any suggestions?

```
struct PrintHTMLView: UIViewControllerRepresentable
{
    var htmlString: String
    var title: String
    
    typealias UIViewControllerType = UIViewController
    
    fileprivate let controller = UIViewController()
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController
    {
        controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context)
    {
       let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
       printInfo.jobName = title
       printInfo.outputType = .general
            
       let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
       printController.printInfo = printInfo
       printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true
            
       let formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: htmlString)
       formatter.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 72, left: 72, bottom: 72, right: 72)
       printController.printFormatter = formatter     
       printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
    }
}
```

Code snippet of call to invoke the above...

```
Button("Print")
{
  self.printShowing.toggle()
}.sheet(isPresented: $printShowing)
{
  PrintHTMLView(htmlString: html, title: "Report")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is fixed variant. The main point is that `UIPrintInteractionController` shows own sheet, so it is not needed for it, and `updateUIViewController` is for different purpose - update content on external data change, so all preparations should be made in `makeUIViewController`.

*Note: `UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter` reference should be kept in properties otherwise it is lost and result in crash on print sheet close.*

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image: demo]

```
struct PrintHTMLView: UIViewControllerRepresentable
{
    let title: String
    let formatter: UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter
    let callback: () -> ()

    init(htmlString: String, title: String, completion: @escaping () -> () = {}) {
        self.title = title
        self.callback = completion

        formatter = UIMarkupTextPrintFormatter(markupText: htmlString)
        formatter.perPageContentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 72, left: 72, bottom: 72, right: 72)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UIViewController
    {
        let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
        printInfo.jobName = title
        printInfo.outputType = .general

        let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
        printController.printInfo = printInfo
        printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true

        printController.printFormatter = formatter

        let controller = UIViewController()
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: { _, _, _ in
                printController.printFormatter = nil
                self.callback()
            })
        }
        return controller
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewController, context: Context)
    {
    }
}

struct TestPrintController: View {
    @State private var printShowing = false
    var body: some View {
        Button("Print")
        {
            self.printShowing = true
        }
        .background(Group {
            if self.printShowing {
                PrintHTMLView(htmlString: "Test String", title: "Report") {
                    self.printShowing = false
                }
            }
        })

    }
}
```