# Printing function for SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, printing, view

I am stuck. I wanted to code a printing function for SwiftUI. But unfortunately there is a problem with the 'view'. I got the message 'Value of type 'ContentView' has no member 'view' ' . Perhaps someone knows a solution for my problem? Underneath, you can see my entire code.
Thanks for any help/hints.

```
import SwiftUI

        
        Button(action: {
            
            func printMe(){
                
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds, true, 0)
                let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
                View?.layer.render(in: context!)
                let imageFromCurrentView = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                imageFromCurrentView?.pngData()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                
                if UIPrintInteractionController.canPrint((imageFromCurrentView?.pngData())!) {
                    let printInfo = UIPrintInfo(dictionary: nil)
                    printInfo.jobName = "Drucke ein Bild!"
                    printInfo.outputType = UIPrintInfo.OutputType.general
                    printInfo.duplex = UIPrintInfo.Duplex.longEdge
                    
                    let printController = UIPrintInteractionController.shared
                    printController.printInfo = printInfo
                    printController.showsNumberOfCopies = true
                    printController.printingItem = imageFromCurrentView
                    printController.present(animated: true, completionHandler: nil)
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text("Print")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/63000943/12299030?

Comment: Try the [Apple SwiftUI Tutorials](https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui) it seems like you are missing the very basics. Some time with those will save you a lot of time troubleshooting. Functions are not declared inside buttons they are called but not declared.

Comment: in other words, put that function outside the `View body`, and have the `Button` inside  the `View` `var body: some View {...}` that calls the function, like `printMe()`. Without knowing the **very basics** you will struggle to code anything using SwiftUI. At the very least do the tutorial, as mentioned above.

Comment: @Asperi: Thanks for this link. It works but it's not this kind of printing function which I am looking for.

Comment: @yesterday: Thanks for the link and your hints. I will check this tutorial. Concerning my code above. It works if you do not code an app with SwiftUI. I have tried to 'translate' this code for SwiftUI but it seems to be not so easy to do that.